# jQuery: if this or that > each()

Tags: jquery

```
$("a.foo").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bar');
});

$("p > a").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bar');
});​
```

If `$("a.foo")` or `if $("p > a")` - How could I join these to one call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine selector by separating with comma. To just add a class you do not need each.

```
$("a.foo, p > a").addClass('bar');
```

If you have many statement for processing then you need to use each.

```
$("a.foo, p > a").each(function() {
     //Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `each` if you are just gonna call a jQuery method like `addClass`:

```
$("a.foo, p > a").addClass("bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("a.foo, p > a").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With a comma, just like in CSS:

```
$("a.foo, p > a")
```